# Wordpress Lazy Loading using Pagination

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

im doing a lazy loading with WP_Query Pagination
it's working fine but the content duplicate itself when it reaches it's end
and when i search for a specific result it shows the result correctly 
but after that it still want to do lazy load so it load random data

here is my code

lazy-load.php

```
    <?php 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback(){
    // check_ajax_referer( 'load_more_posts', 'security' );
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'unit',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    if ( !empty($_POST['taxonomy']) &&  !empty($_POST['term_id']) ){
        $args['tax_query'] = array (
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $_POST['taxonomy'],
                'terms'    => $_POST['term_id'],
            ),
        );
    }
    if ( ! is_null($_POST['offer']) ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'    => 'WAKEB_hot',
            'value'  => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        );
    }
    if ( ! is_null($_POST['purpose']) ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'    => 'WAKEB_vacation',
            'value'  => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        );
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['project'])){
        $args['meta_query'] = array (
            array(
                'key' => 'WAKEB_project',
                'value' => $_POST['project'],
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        );
    }
    // start buffer 
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        while($query->have_posts()){ $query->the_post(); 
            get_template_part("template-parts/units"); 
        } 
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();
    // start buffered data in data variable
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    wp_send_json_success( $data );
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_projects_by_ajax', 'load_projects_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_projects_by_ajax', 'load_projects_by_ajax_callback');

function load_projects_by_ajax_callback(){
    // check_ajax_referer( 'load_more_posts', 'security' );
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    if ( ! is_null($_POST['ptype']) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array (
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pptypes',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $_POST['ptype'],
            ),
        );
    }
    if ( !empty($_POST['taxonomy']) &&  !empty($_POST['term_id']) ){
        $args['tax_query'] = array (
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $_POST['taxonomy'],
                'terms'    => $_POST['term_id'],
            ),
        );
    }
    // start buffer 
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while($query->have_posts()){ $query->the_post();
            get_template_part("template-parts/projects");
        }
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();
    // start buffered data in data variable
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    wp_send_json_success( $data );
    wp_die();
}
```

lazy-load.js

```
    $('.unit-terms li a').each( function() {
    if ( this.href == window.location.href ) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    }
});
```

main.js

```
    (function($){
  $('.isotope a').on('click', function(){
    $('.isotope .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    if(filter=='*'){
    $('.property').show();
  }else{
    $('.property').not(filter).hide();
    $('.property'+filter).show();
  }
  return false;
  });
})(jQuery);
```

so how can i make it work? i don't know what im doing wrong here

Here is the repo link for the full project 
https://github.com/Ov3rControl/hoomerz

Comment: Do you have a link to look at to see the behavior?

Comment: http://beta.hoomerz.com/find-properties/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, now I understand what you meant ;) During lazy load you send to backend only page number without current state of filters and / or search string. So it sends all posttype items based on page number only. You should send also current state of filters

main.js: add this to your after-page-load function:

var currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
var searchQuery = urlObj.searchParams.get("k");

lazy-load.js: add search param to data posted to backend

```
var data = {
    'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
    'page': page,
    'search: searchQuery // new field
};
```

lazy-load.php: add search param to WP_Query

```
if ( isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search']) ){ // new section
    $args['s'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['search']);
}
```

That's example for text search filter. For all filters you must

```
1. match every filter from front (URL get param) (main.js)
2. than put it in data object sent to backend (lazy-load.js)
3. address this variable in lazy-load.php in if(isset($_POST['param-name'])) section ( new or existing one as there are some )
```

Comment: thanks very much can you provide a simple code for doing that ?
i added the code to lazy-load.php and lazy-load.js but i can't get it to work 
thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try without ob_start() / ob_get_clean().  Also if you generate html instead of raw data structure, I would simply print it to output without wp_send_json_success().

Other solution would be sending raw data (1. array in php, 2. json_encode(), 3. wp_send_json() ) and than processing in javascript (dynamic dom element creation after request to backend made).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer im really new to wp can you provide a simple modification to my code? Thanks very much

Comment: Provide your js  that covers sending request to backend and then building new list item in browser. What you showed in lazy-load.js and main.js is rather logic for filtering items and setting active style. Or better - give us link to working dev version.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer here is the working repo
https://github.com/Ov3rControl/hoomerz - we are using php 5.6
it's public and im also uploading all in-one migration for the project

Comment: I duplicated your lazy load code and it seems to work ok (both: backend and js side). Two suggestions for further investigation:
1/ do you use wpml as lang plugin? I found some clues in code that you do. If so - check this manual about wpml and ajax: [link](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/enabling-language-cookie-to-support-ajax-filtering/) 
2/ As usual with Wordpress, try to turn off all plugins and check if this lazy load works ok, than turn on each plugin

Comment: i tried disabling all the plugins same issue i use WPML for arabic but the issue is in english 
here is a link you can see clearly here i searched for ainsokhna it got the 1st 2 results right but the rest is irrelevent data 
http://beta.hoomerz.com/find-properties/?k=Ain+Sokhna&area1=&area2=&price1=&price2=