# Wordpress Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, lazy-loading

hello I was implementing lazy loading in WordPress through pagination
it works fine but it repeats the data when I scroll down 
for example, if the expected results are 4 posts only and I scrolled down it keeps repeating those 4 posts
 here is my javascript code

```
<script>
$ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
var urlString = window.location.href;
var url = new URL( urlString );
var offer = url.searchParams.get("offer");
var purpose = url.searchParams.get("purpose");
jQuery(function($){
    $('.property-listings').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.property-listings .load-more'),
        page = 2,
        loading = false,
        scrollHandling = {
            allow: true,
            reallow: function() {
                scrollHandling.allow = true;
            },
            delay: 400
        };
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if ( ! loading && scrollHandling.allow ) {
            scrollHandling.allow = false;
            setTimeout( scrollHandling.reallow,scrollHandling.delay );
            var offset = $(button).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if ( 2000 > offset ) {
                loading = true;
                $('.loader-wrap').css({display: 'flex'});
                var data = {
                    'action':       'load_posts_by_ajax',
                    'page':         page,
                };
                if ( offer ) {
                    data.offer = offer;
                }
                if ( purpose ) {
                    data.purpose = purpose;
                }
                // console.log(data);
                $.post($ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    if( response.data != "" ) {
                        $('.property-listings .content-wrap').append(response.data);
                        $('.property-listings').append( button );
                        page++;
                        $('.loader-wrap').css({display: 'none'});
                        loading = false;
                    }else{
                        $('.loader-wrap').css({display: 'none'});
                        scrollHandling.allow = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

is there is a way to tell it to stop if it found another card with the same name for example

here is the WordPress code also

```
    <?php

/**

 * The template for displaying find properties page.

 *

 * This is the template that displays only find-properties page.

 *

 * @package WAKEB

 */

get_header();

if (!empty($_GET['region'])){

    $args =array(
        'post_type'      => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'    => 'regions',
                'field'       => 'id',
                'terms'       => $_GET['region'],
            ),
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $projectsid[] = get_the_ID();
        }
    }else{
        $projectsid=array(0);
    }
}
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'unit',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => 1,
);
if (!empty($_GET['ctype'])){
    $args['tax_query'] = array (
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ctypes',
            'terms'    => $_GET['ctype'],
        ),
    );
}
if (!empty($_GET['ptype'])){
    $args['tax_query'] = array (
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'uptypes',
            'terms'    => $_GET['ptype'],
        ),
    );
}
if (!empty($_GET['pro'])){
    $args['meta_key'] = 'WAKEB_project';
    $args['meta_value'] = $_GET['pro'];
}
if(!empty($_GET['k'])){
    $args['s'] = $_GET['k'];
}
if(isset($projectsid)){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_project',
        'value'  => $projectsid,
        'compare' => 'IN',
        'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}
if(!empty($_GET['area1']) && !empty($_GET['area2'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_unitarea',
        'value'  => array($_GET['area1'], $_GET['area2']),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}elseif(!empty($_GET['area1'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_unitarea',
        'value'  => $_GET['area1'],
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}elseif(!empty($_GET['area2'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_unitarea',
        'value'  => $_GET['area2'],
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}
if(!empty($_GET['price1']) && !empty($_GET['price2'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_price',
        'value'  => array($_GET['price1'], $_GET['price2']),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}elseif(!empty($_GET['price1'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_price',
        'value'  => $_GET['price1'],
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}elseif(!empty($_GET['price2'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_price',
        'value'  => $_GET['price2'],
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type'   => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}
if(!empty($_GET['purpose'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_vacation',
        'value'  => '1',
        'compare' => '=',
    );
}
if(!empty($_GET['offer'])){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'    => 'WAKEB_hot',
        'value'  => '1',
        'compare' => '=',
    );
}

?>
<div class="fixed-search">
    <form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/find-properties/" name="find-units">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="<?php _e('Search', 'WAKEB'); ?>" name="k" id="k"> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <div id="toggle-ctype" class="filter"><?php _e('Filter by contract type', 'WAKEB'); ?></div>
                    <div class="dropdwon" id="ctype-select">
                        <?php 
                            $ctype_args = array (
                                'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
                                'hide_empty'  => false,
                            );
                            $Contract_types = get_terms('ctypes', $ctype_args);
                            foreach ($Contract_types as $ctype){
                                if ( !get_field( 'hide', 'ctypes_'. $ctype->term_id ) ) :
                                    echo '<div class="checkbox">';
                                    echo '<label  class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="ctype[]" value="'.$ctype->term_id.'"><span class="checkmark"></span>'.$ctype->name.'</label>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                endif;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <div id="toggle-ptype" class="filter"><?php _e('Filter by purpose type', 'WAKEB'); ?></div>
                    <div class="dropdwon" id="ptype-select">
                        <?php 
                            $ptype_args = array (
                                'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
                                'hide_empty'  => false,
                            );
                            $Purpose_types = get_terms('uptypes', $ptype_args);
                            foreach ($Purpose_types as $ptype){
                                if ( !get_field( 'hide', 'uptypes_'. $ptype->term_id ) ) :
                                    echo '<div class="checkbox">';
                                    echo '<label  class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="ptype[]" value="'.$ptype->term_id.'"><span class="checkmark"></span>'.$ptype->name.'</label>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                endif;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <div id="toggle-proj" class="filter"><?php _e('Filter by compound', 'WAKEB'); ?></div>
                    <div class="dropdwon" id="proj-select">
                        <?php
                            $pro_args = array ('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1,);
                            $query = new WP_Query( $pro_args );
                            if($query->have_posts()){
                                while($query->have_posts()){
                                    $query->the_post();
                                    echo '<div class="checkbox">';
                                    echo '<label  class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="pro[]" value="'.get_the_ID().'"><span class="checkmark"></span>';
                                            $name = rwmb_meta('WAKEB_card_name');
                                            if ( $name ) { echo $name; }else{ the_title(); }
                                    echo '</label>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-field">
                    <div id="toggle-regions" class="filter"><?php _e('Filter by region', 'WAKEB'); ?></div>
                    <div class="dropdwon" id="regions-select">
                        <?php 
                            echo '<ul>';
                            draw_tree_for_regions(0);
                            function draw_tree_for_regions($p_id){
                                $reg_args = array (
                                    'orderby'    => 'menu_order',
                                    'hide_empty' => false,
                                    'parent'     => $p_id,
                                );
                                $allregions = get_terms('regions', $reg_args);
                                foreach ($allregions as $region){
                                    if ( !get_field( 'hide', 'regions_'. $region->term_id ) ) :
                                        echo '<li><div class="checkbox">';
                                        echo '<label  class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="region[]" value="'.$region->term_id.'"><span class="checkmark"></span>'.$region->name.'</label>';
                                        echo '</div>';
                                        $children=get_term_children($region->term_id, 'regions');
                                        if($children){
                                            echo '<ul>';
                                            draw_tree_for_regions($region->term_id);
                                            echo '</ul>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</li>';
                                    endif;
                                }
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <div id="toggle-area" class="filter"><?php _e('Filter by Area', 'WAKEB'); ?></div>
                    <div class="dropdwon" id="area-select">
                        <div class="checkbox"><input type="search" placeholder="<?php _e('From', 'WAKEB'); ?>" name="area1" id="area1" > </div>
                        <div class="checkbox"><input type="search" placeholder="<?php _e('To', 'WAKEB'); ?>" name="area2" id="area2" ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <div id="toggle-price" class="filter"><?php _e('Filter by Price', 'WAKEB'); ?></div>
                    <div class="dropdwon" id="price-select">
                        <div class="checkbox"><input type="search" placeholder="<?php _e('From', 'WAKEB'); ?>" name="price1" id="price1" > </div>
                        <div class="checkbox"><input type="search" placeholder="<?php _e('To', 'WAKEB'); ?>" name="price2" id="price2" > </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <button type="submit"><?php _e( 'Search', 'WAKEB' ); ?></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<section class="content-search-result page-section">
    <div class="section-title"><h2><?php _e('AVAILABLE UNITS', 'WAKEB'); ?></h2></div>
    <ul class="unit-terms">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <?php
                $tax_args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'utypes', 'hide_empty' => false );
                $ptypes = get_terms( $tax_args );
                foreach ( $ptypes as $ptype ) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $ptype->term_id ) .'">'. $ptype->name .'</a></li>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <?php
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if($query->have_posts()){ ?>
            <ul class="property-listings">
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <?php 
                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                            get_template_part("template-parts/units");
                        endwhile; 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <?php echo '<div class="loader-wrap"><div class="lds-facebook"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>';
        }else{
            echo '<div class="no-result">'. _e( 'No results found...', 'WAKEB' ) .'</div>';
        }
    ?>
</section>
```

here is a link to the full working WordPress repo (using PHP 5.6)
https://github.com/Ov3rControl/hoomerz

it repeated the data as shown 
after that it still load irrelevant data from what i was searching for 
for example if i was searching for apartments in egypt
it gets all apartments from egypt THEN repeats them THEN when i scroll i still get data but from irrelevant places like USA for example

here is a live link to the problem 
http://beta.hoomerz.com/find-properties/?k=&region%5B%5D=218&area1=&area2=&price1=&price2= 
the search should only be the 1st post only and shouldn't load any other irrelevent data

Comment: Please use your browser debug tools to check the AJAX requests you're making to the server. Do you increase the page number correctly? Does the server return different data every time, or the same data? i.e. is the problem in how you're making the request, or how the server is responding to it, or how you're processing the server's response.

Comment: thanks for you response i updated the question can you please help im really new 
Thanks very much for your fast response

Comment: it repeated the data as shown 
after that it still load irrelevant data from what i was searching for 
for example if i was searching for apartments in egypt
it gets all apartments from egypt THEN repeats them THEN when i scroll i still get data but from irrelevant places like USA for example

Comment: Is that the offer and purpose parameters? I didn't see those in your request log. Maybe you're not copying them into the second page requests correctly?

Comment: no they are not the offer and purpose parameters i deleted them and the problem still occures

Comment: How does your ajax request know that you're only searching for apartments in Egypt then?

Comment: Using the $_GET['region'] i think ? i m confused now

Comment: change `'paged' => 1,` to `'paged' => $paged,` you are always getting page 1..

Comment: i changed it as you said still same results the content are repeating infinitly

Answer (score 0):

Are you outputting the script code above from PHP? You've got this line:

`$ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';`

which won't work unless the entire script you show above is in a php file and part of an echo() or print() statement. Use [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to safely and correctly output the value of admin_url('amin-ajax.php') in your HTML, then use JavaScript to get the value from the DOM and use it as necessary.

Beyond that, your AJAX call uses $.post, but your PHP is checking $_GET. Pick a method and use it - in this case, $_GET is more appropriate.

Comment: it's already localized
i did what you said still same problem

Comment: Already localized how and where? I don't see a call to wp_localize_script() anywhere in the code you posted, I just see PHP in a JavaScript file. When I say use the wp_localize_script() function I mean output the value of admin_url('admin-ajax.php') in the HTML source so you can use it in your JavaScript.

Comment: yes i just did but didn't update it in the repo 
the problem turned out that During lazy load you send to backend only page number without current state of filters and / or search string. So it sends all posttype items based on page number only. You should send also current state of filters but still can't figure it out :(

Comment: here is the same issue but with 100 Reputation for correct ansswer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637182/wordpress-lazy-loading-using-pagination/56752135#56752135

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Noo im still lost can't write the code maybe i will make another question